# Multiplication with int and str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am completely baffled at this seemingly simple problem that I have.  I want to define a function that will take the input, which can be a str or int and double it.  For example, if the input is `'foo'`, then the output will be `'foofoo'`.  Likewise, if the input is (9), the output will be 18.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Here is what I have so far:

```
def double(x):
    """returns two times a number if input is a number, returns double the size of the string inputted, if input is a string
str -> str; int -> int"""
    if x is :
        return x*2
    if x is :
        return x*2
```

Comment: Have your *tried* multiplying by 2? `'foo'*2 == 'foofoo'` and 
`4*2 == 8` in Python.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, and the `*` operator works for both integers and strings, so you don't need to care about what the function input is.

Comment: thanks everyone, had a brain fart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
def double(x):
    return x+x
```

or

```
def double(x):
    return x*2
```

Both should work as:

- the `+` operator is overloaded to perform concatenation when arguments are strings;
- the `*` operator is overloaded to "duplicate" when one argument is a string.

As Python is dynamically typed, the choice of the *real* operation performed will be made at run-time, depending the type of the operands.

---

More formally, to quote [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> The `*` (multiplication) operator yields the product of its arguments. **The arguments must either both be numbers, or one argument must be an integer and the other must be a sequence**. In the former case, the numbers are converted to a common type and then multiplied together. In the latter case, sequence repetition is performed; a negative repetition factor yields an empty sequence.
>
> [...]
>
> The `+` (addition) operator yields the sum of its arguments. **The arguments must either both be numbers or both be sequences of the same type**. In the former case, the numbers are converted to a common type and then added together. In the latter case, the sequences are concatenated.

---

If you're curious, from the sources or `Python3.3.6/Objects/abstract.c` (The code for `PyNumber_Mul` is quite comparable) :

```
PyObject *
PyNumber_Add(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    PyObject *result = binary_op1(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_add));
    if (result == Py_NotImplemented) {
        PySequenceMethods *m = v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
        Py_DECREF(result);
        if (m && m->sq_concat) {
            return (*m->sq_concat)(v, w);
        }
        result = binop_type_error(v, w, "+");
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, the interpreter will first try to perform an addition using the special method `__add__` defined for the left operand. If this one returns `NotImplemented`, it will try to interpret the left operand as a sequence and perform a concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply the input by two. If it is a string, it will concatenate twice. If it is a number, it will double.

```
user = raw_input('Enter input: ')
print user * 2
```

Look at the Python Documentation. This is taken straight from it.

> Strings can be concatenated (glued together) with the `+` operator, and repeated with `*`:

```
>>> # 3 times 'un', followed by 'ium'
>>> 3 * 'un' + 'ium'
'unununium'
```